# The ALT key in Dwarf Fortress (13.10)

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am trying to play DF adventure mode, and when I press ALT + (Direction) to navigate dangerous terrain, it does not register the action.

I have tried disabling the key through the Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Launcher menu, but it does nothing. It shows the key as disable, yet I still do not have access to the ALT key within DF.

I cannot find any other fixes anywhere.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install an alternate terminal emulator (such as gnome-terminal) and run Dwarf Fortress in that.

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

Launch terminal:

```
gnome-terminal
```

From the new gnome terminal window start Dwarf Fortress

```
cd my_video_games/df_linux
./df
```

I had encountered this same problem when trying to run Dwarf Fortress with xterm in Debian Jessie.  These were the steps I took to resolve the issue.